# How to use die() for twitter api using PHP

Tags: twitter

I am using twitter api in my website. I want to use something like die() in order to ignore api when it has not access to the internet to prevent getting error. I am using WAMP for programming and each time I try to refresh the page, I get api error and hence, it prevents the rest of the page from loading. I need something like this:

```
$tweets = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $twitteruser,  'exclude_replies' => true, 'include_rts' => false)) **or die()**;
```

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that you could use :

```
//Try to connect to Twitter API, stop attempts after 1 second
$isReachable = @fsockopen("api.twitter.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 1);

if ($isReachable){
   fclose($isReachable); // Close connection
   // Get your tweets
   $tweets = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $twitteruser,  'exclude_replies' => true, 'include_rts' => false))
 }
```

This code checks if Twitter API is reachable.
If no response has been received after 1 second, just continue execution without using Twitter API.
Note that if you're not connected to internet, your page will load 1 second slower.